# Rails seems to require me to precompile before CSS will take effect on Development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, precompile

I am messing around with CSS in rails and have created this masterpiece of a css file:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

but rails will not load this locally until I precompile assets. This strikes me as relatively odd behavior. Does anyone know why?

I have this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>` in my application.html.erb and `config.serve_static_asset = true` in my `config/environment/development.rb`.

I guess it still works, but being able to reload without precompiling would be nice.

Comment: I'm guessing your assets file is in app/assets, once precompiled I believe it moves your necessary assets to the public/assets. This is just a guess though and based purely on speculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running 'rake assets:clean'  to remove your old precompiled assets.

Comment: I think this would work as well. I actually found another answer just before you posted. I just deleted the public assets folder. The way I am thinking of it is that like the public#index file Rails will default into it.